# HTTP transfer rate

Tags: http

Is there a way to specify, in a HTTP header, the transfer rate of the content?

Comment: What do you need a transfer rate for?

Comment: For example transferring a file using bsd sockets api for .net

Comment: Until you posted that comment, I thought I knew what you where trying to ask. Now I have no idea. You might want to update the question with more details on the problem you are trying to solve :)

Comment: send the sendtime.Ticks return message with server receivetime.Ticks
, add them, divide by 2 subtract sendtime.Ticks. then you have a time.
divide amount of data you have sent in that time.and the result is Bps

Comment: I don't understand why this would belong in a header.  From the point of view of the server, if it wanted serve at a certain speed, why would it send this info to the client?  Most sensibly, it would seem it should just simply send at that speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're writing your own HTTP server, no.

But you can throttle the connection in the client, by reading from the socket only at a certain speed. Due to buffering at the server, network, and your client, the initial part of the file will be sent as fast as the server and network can support. But once all buffers are filled up, the connection speed will be limited by your read speed.

Answer (score 0):

No, the data is always transfered as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, here you have the possible headers you can specify:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers